# Why DBus cannot call this property?

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus

I'm trying to make a call to a BLE device using DBus in Ubuntu Desktop 23.10.

This is DBus definition of the device in bluez:

```
user@machine-desktop:~$ sudo busctl introspect org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_12_05_FF_13_A0
NAME                                TYPE      SIGNATURE RESULT/VALUE                             FLAGS
org.bluez.Device1                   interface -         -                                        -
.CancelPairing                      method    -         -                                        -
.Connect                            method    -         -                                        -
.ConnectProfile                     method    s         -                                        -
.Disconnect                         method    -         -                                        -
.DisconnectProfile                  method    s         -                                        -
.Pair                               method    -         -                                        -
.Adapter                            property  o         "/org/bluez/hci0"                        emits-change
.Address                            property  s         "00:1C:05:FF:13:A0"                      emits-change
.AddressType                        property  s         "public"                                 emits-change
.Alias                              property  s         "Nonin3230_502726737"                    emits-change writable
.Appearance                         property  q         3137                                     emits-change
.Blocked                            property  b         false                                    emits-change writable
.Bonded                             property  b         true                                     emits-change
.Class                              property  u         -                                        emits-change
.Connected                          property  b         false                                    emits-change
.Icon                               property  s         -                                        emits-change
.LegacyPairing                      property  b         false                                    emits-change
.ManufacturerData                   property  a{qv}     -                                        emits-change
.Modalias                           property  s         -                                        emits-change
.Name                               property  s         "Nonin3230_502726737"                    emits-change
.Paired                             property  b         true                                     emits-change
.RSSI                               property  n         -                                        emits-change
.ServiceData                        property  a{sv}     -                                        emits-change
.ServicesResolved                   property  b         false                                    emits-change
.Sets                               property  a{oa{sv}} -                                        emits-change
.Trusted                            property  b         true                                     emits-change writable
.TxPower                            property  n         -                                        emits-change
.UUIDs                              property  as        6 "00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb… emits-change
.WakeAllowed                        property  b         -                                        emits-change writable
org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable interface -         -                                        -
.Introspect                         method    -         s                                        -
org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties     interface -         -                                        -
.Get                                method    ss        v                                        -
.GetAll                             method    s         a{sv}                                    -
.Set                                method    ssv       -                                        -
```

I'm trying to get *ServiceData* property value, using :

```
user@machine-desktop:~$ dbus-send --system --dest=org.bluez --print-reply /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_1C_05_FF_13_A0 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:org.bluez.Device1 string:ServiceData
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such property 'ServiceData'
```

Shouldn't I be able to invoke property and get value?

Regards.

EDIT: forget to say archis arm64. Raspberry PI 4b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After skimming through the BlueZ source code (src/device.c), it seems that the service reports properties as non-existent when the corresponding struct field is null.

They remain visible in the "introspection" XML as that is defined statically, but BlueZ has its own handler for the Get() method which will "manually" return a D-Bus error in case the field is null.

(Most likely the reason for doing so is because D-Bus has neither nullable types nor 'maybe' types, so perhaps the BlueZ developers wanted to avoid confusion that might occur if null properties returned `0` or `""` when they're empty?)

So it seems you should either consider the error to be expected and handle it in your code – or, alternatively, use GetAll() to get a dict with all properties that "exist".